# Можно ли найти большие массивы данных для своих программ?

Tags: python-3.x

Очень часто приходится копаться в "песочнице", разбирая какие-то методы, функции и т.д. И каждый раз для этого приходится писать свои листы, кортежи и прочее с данными. Это немного утомительно и я хотел бы спросить - есть ли какой-то сервис, который, может быть, генерирует листы на 100+ значений или что-то, отдающее JSON, как в JS?

Небольшое пояснение:

Нужны "базы с учебными данными". К примеру, лист с именами или ещё что-то такое. Не просто `list(range(100))`, а что-то сложнее.
К примеру
`['Привет', 'Я', 'Большой', 'Лист', 'c', 'разными', 'словами']`

Comment: Не понятно, что именно вам нужно - какая-то база с "учебными" данными, или какой-то инструмент для упрощения обработки данных, или что?

Comment: `list(range(100))`.

Comment: Можно взять [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) и генерировать себе любые списки с произвольными данными.

Comment: Похожие вопросы: [поиск: "где взять базу"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D0%B7%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Берёте любой текст, да хоть этого вопроса, делаете ему `.split()`, да любой текст в интернете можно взять, чтобы побольше был. Можно потом ещё через `random.choices` с повторами этот набор слов взять произвольного размера.

Comment: https://ru.lipsum.com/feed/html